# How can I stop the Clicking function While it is finish Animation?

Tags: jquery

I need to know how can I stop the clicking function while it finishing the Animation

here is my code

```
 $(function () {
     $('legend').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle("slow");
     });
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "stop the clicking function"?

Comment: What i meant, is that I do not want 'legend' to keep on clicking while the toggle function is animating

Comment: He means don't allow the click event to fire if the animation is in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your selector slightly to exclude [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) elements using [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
 $(function () {
     $('legend').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().find('.content:not(:animated)').slideToggle('slow');
     });
 });
```

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/acKtG/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Simply check for an 'animating' bool flag. During animation, return out of the click event, else set the flag and animate, then reset the flag on the animation complete callback:

```
 $(function () {
     $('legend').click(function () {
         if($(this).data('animating') !== true) {
             $(this).data('animating',true);
             $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle("slow", function(){$(this).data('animating',false);});
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: I see this code: `$('legend').click(function () {$(this).parent().find('.content:not(:animated)').slideToggle('slow');});` not the code I provided.

Comment: Dude you're using `jQuery 1.2.6` - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js update your codebase!